# Angular 6 merge two array to count the length of key

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have an array of two objects which has another array of objects, i want the count of all objects of property "value" in the following sample.

```
var data = [
  { 
  "x": "123",
  "values": [
    { 
      "a": "1"
    }, 
   { 
     "b": "2" 
    }
  ] 
},   { 
  "y": "123",
  "values": [
    { 
      "a": "1"
    }, 
   { 
     "b": "2" 
    }
  ] 
}
];
```

I have used the following logic :-

```
  let _data = data.RESULT;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(_data));
      _data.forEach(element => {
        this.someObj = element;
      });
```

The expected result should be the length of values property, i.e. 4

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Please also add the wanted result.

Comment: please check now i have added

Comment: Please add the expected result of the above array.

Comment: @Manav check my answer for a single line approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find only length of "values" array then you need to do this

```
data = [
  { 
  "x": "123",
  "values": [
    { 
      "a": "1"
    }, 
   { 
     "b": "2" 
    }
  ] 
},   { 
  "y": "123",
  "values": [
    { 
      "a": "1"
    }, 
   { 
     "b": "2" 
    }
  ] 
}
]

length = 0;

constructor() {
  this.data.forEach((d) => {
    length = length + d.values.length;
  });
  console.log('length', length);
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3daqcy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Created a function that adds the lengths of the `values` array

```js
var arr = [
  { 
  "x": "123",
  "values": [
    { 
      "a": "1"
    }, 
   { 
     "b": "2" 
    }
  ] 
},   { 
  "y": "123",
  "values": [
    { 
      "a": "1"
    }, 
   { 
     "b": "2" 
    }
  ] 
}
]

function getKeysLength(arr){
  var count  = 0;
  arr.forEach((val)=>{count= count+ val.values.length})
  return count
}

var ans  = getKeysLength(arr);
console.log("ans",ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in a single line then you can do it with `map` and `reduce`,`map` creates a new array with the elements as the length of the `values` property and `reduce` calculates the sum of the new array elements . Which gives you the sum of the length of all `values` property arrays.

Here is the code below -

```
let data = [
  { 
  "x": "123",
  "values": [
    { 
      "a": "1"
    }, 
   { 
     "b": "2" 
    }
  ] 
},   { 
  "y": "123",
  "values": [
    { 
      "a": "1"
    }, 
   { 
     "b": "2" 
    }
  ] 
}
];

let totalLength = data.map(x => x.values.length).reduce((a,b) => a+b,0);
console.log(temparr);
```

Here is a working Stackblitz with Angular 6

https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-ewa5tb?file=src/app/app.component.ts